# Firestore offline persistence: how much of the database is cached locally?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

When you initialize Firestore with offline persistence enabled, what happens? Is the entire database downloaded into the cache at that point? Or are things only cached as you access them?

Answer (score 0):

Data is only added to the local database when you attach an observer to it, or when the local client writes to it. Without any observers or writes, the local database will remain empty.